# Ms Word Doc Into Memory Stream and Saving As Char To Database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-word, interop, memorystream

I want to read a ms word document exists in Desktop and save whole text to SQL database as Text, not Byte[]. Because the program written by the programmer works in company before me; coded the program will work like "only read NVARCHAR value from the column and show to user".

I tried using RichTextBox for saving text to the database converted from Abby Fine Reader but RTB Int32 Max Value supplies 2,147,483,647 chars. When I C/P the text(such as word doc including 100 pages, it only get 10-11-12 pages of char.)

And also viewed Memory Stream but as i said at the top of the topic: i dont want to save word chars as Byte[]. 
What is the way? I dont have any idea.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I dont want from you the code. I said what i have tried RichTextBox and Viewed MemoryStream topics on the internet. But all topics about the memory stream(for ms word or .txt files) use Byte array for saving the output. Is there an another way of this. I want to save word's whole text as NVarchar. Also the question is readable and simple!

Comment: [Data Type Conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx)